# https request--Python code to C++

Tags: python, c++, api, curl

i have a function written in Python which calls Robinhood(a stock trading broker) API to get quote data("get_quote(self, symbol)" function in following code snipshot). And it works fine. Correct market data was returned.

```
import requests
import urllib

class Robinhood(object):

# All known endpoints as of September 5th, 2015
endpoints = {

    "quotes": "https://api.robinhood.com/quotes/",
    "user": "https://api.robinhood.com/user/",
    "user/additional_info": "https://api.robinhood.com/user/additional_info/",
    "user/basic_info": "https://api.robinhood.com/user/basic_info/",
    "user/employment": "https://api.robinhood.com/user/employment/",
    "user/investment_profile": "https://api.robinhood.com/user/investment_profile/",
    "watchlists": "https://api.robinhood.com/watchlists/"
    }

def get_quote(self, symbol):
    ''' Returns a qoute object for a given symbol including all data returned by Robinhood's API'''
    data = { 'symbols' : symbol }
    res = self.session.get(self.endpoints['quotes'], params=data)
    if res.status_code == 200:
        return res.json()['results']
    else:
        raise Exception("Could not retrieve quote: " + res.text)
```

I tried to implement this logic in C++ using Curl library. But it doesn't work. There was no compile or run time error but the program returned a single unreadable character instead of the market price of stock. It looks to me like my URL is not correctly set up but I couldn't figure out how to fix it. Does someone have an idea? Thank you!

```
std::string RobinhoodAPI::GetQuote(std::string ticker)
{
 struct response resStr;
init_string(&resStr);
std::string url = "https://api.robinhood.com/quotes/symbols=AVP/";
curl_easy_setopt(curl, CURLOPT_URL, url.c_str());
curl_easy_setopt(curl, CURLOPT_WRITEDATA, &resStr);

 resCode = curl_easy_perform(curl);
 std::cout << std::string(resStr.ptr);

 return std::string(resStr.ptr);
}
```

Comment: can you post a runnable example?

Comment: I could. But in both cases it would need your Robinhood username and password to make a connection to the API.

Comment: @MK. the unreadable symbol looks like number zero with question mark inside it.

Answer (score 0):

I have created an open api specification for the unofficial documentation of the robinhood api. With this you can generate http client for most languages.

Please visit here https://github.com/sabareeshkkanan/robinhood for the specification. And please visit this repo for how to generate client using this specification https://github.com/swagger-api/swagger-codegen